# Unable to get test credit card transaction to process in Paypal Hosted Pages

Tags: java, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I want my customers to be able to subscribe to a tiered product which is handled on my end and have the option to either pay by credit card or paypal. I can checkout with paypal and it works fine, but when I try to test a credit card transaction, this is the error screen I get:

[image]

This is the command I use to request a secure token:

```
USER={{user}}&VENDOR={{vendor}}&PARTNER={{partner}}&PWD={{password}}&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=s{{ecureTokenId}}&TRXTYPE=S&AMT={{amount}}&CURRENCY=CAD&VERBOSITY=MEDIUM&L_NAME0={{name}}&L_DESC0={{description}}&L_COST0={{amount}}&L_QTY0=1&ITEMAMT={{amount}}
```

My question is, how do I get a credit card transaction to go through in test mode? I've exhausted my patience reading the Paypal documentation and was unable to find an answer.

This is what shows up in manager.paypal.com

[image]

Regards,

Trevor

Comment: Did you check your manager account to see if transaction actually listed there. You will see the same error when the card is declined  if you haven't set your error url . You can try with this test card number to check once : 4860444400578788 with CVV as "012" and and any future exp date.

Comment: I assume `&SECURETOKENID=s{{ecureTokenId}}` is a typo in your question?

Comment: Yes that's a typoin the question

Answer (score 0):

I contacted paypal manager support and it was a configuration problem. They fixed it on their end then my cc transacations started to go through.